# Setting a variable value as string having [] square parentheses

Tags: tcl

I am trying to write a file (file.txt) through my tcl script having following contents.

```
$ cat file.txt
create_library_domain TIMING
set_attribute library ./sc9mc.lib [find /libraries -library_domain TIMING]
exit
```

Simple strings is fine, they can be double quoted and passed as a variable to put command, but string with braces are not stored in variable: `[find /libraries -library_domain TIMING]` I tried escaping it using `\` but that also didn't work for me.

Code:

```
proc rcRun {} {
    type_run
    global rundir ENTRYfilename curDIR typep
    set rc_entry "create_library_domain TIMING"
    set attr "set_attribute library"
    set evt "[find /libraries -library_domain TIMING]"
    set rd "exit"
    set cmd [concat $attr $ENTRYfilename $evt]
    cd $rundir
    set filename rc.cmd 
    set fileId  [open $filename "w"]
    puts $fileId $rc_entry $cmd $rd
    close $fileId
}
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Do you want to escape the square brackets `[]` so that they can be not treated as a `tcl` command ?

Comment: Yes exactly, only wanted to put this as a string in file.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to literally print the word `[find /libraries -library_domain TIMING]` alone in the file, then the left square bracket `[` should be escaped once with backslash when double quotes used. Or, you can use braces instead.

```
% set evt "\[find /libraries -library_domain TIMING]"
[find /libraries -library_domain TIMING]
% set evt {[find /libraries -library_domain TIMING]}
[find /libraries -library_domain TIMING]
%
```

**Note :**  We don't need to escape the right square bracket `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Escape twice?

```
set evt "\\\[find /libraries -library_domain TIMING\\\]"
```

Comment: @ RomanMishin :  This will return `\[find /libraries -library_domain TIMING\]`. The OP want to write `[find /libraries -library_domain TIMING]` in the file. i.e. without backslash